# printing HABTM results

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

Im using cake 2.0 and im trying to print out the following in my view. i.e the friends of a user i cant get my head around how to print it out. im using a HABTM relationship and it seems to be working.

The controller sends a variable called "$users" to the view but i cant seem to get it print out correctly(im not too familar with Php array's)

Can anyone help me (debug of $users)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 104
                    [username] => admin

                )

            [Friend] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 107
                            [username] => carskitchens

                            [Retailerrelationship] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 12
                                    [retailer_id] => 104
                                    [supplier_id] => 107
                                    [created] => 2012-03-28 10:14:23
                                    [modified] => 2012-03-28 10:14:23
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 112
                            [username] => manufacturer

                            [Retailerrelationship] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 13
                                    [retailer_id] => 104
                                    [supplier_id] => 112
                                    [created] => 2012-03-28 11:26:52
                                    [modified] => 2012-03-28 11:26:52
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any formatting, the loop would be:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
  echo $user['User']['name'];

  foreach($user['Friend'] as $friend)
  {
    echo $friend['username'];
  }
}
```